# How do you find two curves that enclose a set of data points?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graphing-functions, approximation, least-squares

I'd assume you'd use least squares here to first get the best fit line for the data, but I need to specifically minimize the vertical distance between the two curves. Originally, I was thinking I'd find the least squares solution and then compute an upper bound/lower bound summation integral to get two functions that bound the data, but now I'm not so sure about that, and whether it's a right approach or not, since I can't guarantee that the vertical distance between the two curves is at minimum really. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're going to need to put some conditions on your curves to avoid the answer being "the maximum distance between two data points on the same vertical line, or 0 of there aren't any", otherwise you'll have curves that stick together the whole time and just spike up/down to data points.

Comment: What do you mean putting conditions on the curves? How would I know what conditions to put?

Comment: I dunno, pick something suitable. Maybe restrict them to be linear, or quadratic, or exponential, or to lie in some other suitable class of functions.